# Redis transaction on queue

Tags: redis, jedis

I'm using the Redis (v6.2.4) `list` data structure as a queue because the list has both `{lpush, rpop}` and `{rpush, lpop}` commands available. Besides, there is no separate queue data structure in Redis afaik.

There are multiple parallel consumers using this queue. Is it possible to use logical transactions on the queue elements? That is to say, if a consumer removes an item from the queue and if it fails during processing, then the element should be put back in the queue.

I am using Jedis 4.2.3 against a Redis cluster with 3 masters each having 2 replicas.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 5.0, Redis supports [streams](https://redis.io/docs/data-types/streams-tutorial/) and consumer groups, which allow to queue entries and process them through multiple (parallel) consumers.

If a consumer of a consumer group reads an entry from a stream and fails during processing, it can re-read it or any other consumer can [receive the ownership of the pending entries](https://redis.io/commands/xautoclaim/), according to certain criteria (including the idle time).

> I am using Jedis 4.2.3 against a Redis cluster with 3 masters each having 2 replicas.

[Jedis 4.2.3 fully supports Redis streams](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/redis.clients/jedis/4.2.3/redis/clients/jedis/commands/StreamCommands.html); and, of course, streams are supported in Redis cluster.